# PHP Multiple Username & Passwords

Tags: php, authentication

So, this is probably the simplest question I could ever possibly ask.. Though it is driving me insane. In my login system, I have it set up to read the username and password from a standalone file "users.php" inside it contains

```
<?php
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
?>
```

I can not, for the life of me figure out how to make it read multiple usernames and passwords. I have tried multiple different variations... If I just add more $user and $password lines, the login will ONLY accept the last set.

I have tried:

```
<?php
$user = 'username', 'user';
$password = 'password', 'password';
?>

<?php
$user = 'username, user';
$password = 'password, password';
?>
```

and both with " instead of '

if anyone has a suggestion, please let me know :3 Thank you!~

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Could you describe why you want to pass multiple usernames and passwords?

Comment: @Justin to allow different users their own username and password.

Comment: @ChrisRiley : keep it in database ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but if your trying to store multiple users, with different names/pass..

```
<?php
    $usernames = ['john', 'smith', 'simon', 'bob'];
    $passwords = ['2rre', '423dasd', 'D#322', 'd3r23'];

  for($i=0; $i < count($usernames); $i++){
    echo 'username '.$usernames[$i].' has password: '.$passwords[$i].'<br/>';
   }
```

Will echo out:

```
username john has password: 2rre
username smith has password: 423dasd
username simon has password: D#322
username bob has password: d3r23
```

Comment: This approach has a problem - usernames and passwords can easily get 'out of sync', when one of the arrays is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array: `$user = array('username', 'user');`

Then you would reference it with `$user[0]` and `$user[1]`